# Application compatibility among different browsers

Tags: function, browser, cross-browser

I have my application running when i Run on I.E8 it is working ok
but on other browsers like chrome,Firefox or I.E10 the functionality seems  to be bit different.
For instance I have a log out button link that is missing in the other browsers and only visible in i.e8 
my question is for these kind of things what are the exact things that are responsible for these functionality.
Where can I look and what can be the possible fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Web browsers render things differently - this is a very common and frustrating part of web development. Older versions of Internet Explorer seem to be the worst.

To help you be less frustrated for now, I suggest you develop things to work primarily in the latest versions of the more popular browsers (Chrome, Firefox and IE9+), then fix your code to work with the less used browsers afterwards.

You also have discrepancies in default values for browsers. For instance, one browser might include margins in a default value whilst another will not. There are way too many cases for me to list all of the things which are responsible, the only way really is trial and error coupled with reading up online.